# Getting data from database based on today's date

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I have written a query to get today's data from database.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT 
                 Bill_Date as [Bill Date],
                 Customers.Name as [Customer Name],
                 Item, Item_Code as [Item Code], 
                 MRP, Tax_Percentage as [Tax Percentage],
                 Quantity, Amount as Total, 
                 Discount, Amount_After_Discount as [Grand Total],
                 Billing_Type as [Billing Type], 
                 Transaction_Number as [Transaction Number] 
             FROM 
                 POS 
             LEFT JOIN 
                 Customers ON POS.Customer = Customers.Customer_Id 
             WHERE 
                 Bill_Date = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)", con);
```

I am displaying the result to a datagridview. But nothing happens. No data is being retrieved. But there is data in database of today.

Comment: Assuming your code that you have not shown works your problem is because GETDATE returns minutes, seconds, etc, and that won't exactly match any of the stored dates.

Comment: my bill_date column in database has date and time.

Comment: run your query in sql server management studio. I misread your query at first  but as Gordon said, if your field also contains the time then it will not compare equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM POS LEFT JOIN
     Customers
     ON POS.Customer=Customers.Customer_Id
WHERE Bill_Date = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date);
```

I can think of three reasons why this would not return anything:

- There are no records for the current date.
- `Bill_Date` contains the time as well as the date.
- `Bill_Date` is stored as as string and cannot be converted to a date.

You can check the last two pretty easily.  For the second:

```
WHERE cast(Bill_Date as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date);
```

For the third:

```
select bill_date
from <whatever>
where try_convert(date, bill_date) is null;
```

Comment: thnks for the response.
There is record for the current date.
bill_date column is of datetime datatype. yes bill_date column stores date with time also.

Comment: thank you very much. casting bill date as date worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dates are points in time so unless you have removed any time part from the records as you created it you will need to take this into account when querying your data.
Generally I use the form >=date and < (date + 1day) as this captures all time points in a day. In your example this would translate to:

```
WHERE Bill_Date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) AND Bill_Date < CAST((GETDATE() + 1) AS Date)
```